# DevExpress WinForms - looking for a control like Grid in WPF

Tags: wpf, grid, devexpress, controls

Does exists some Grid Control among DevExpress controls for WinForms that behave like the WPF Grid control ?

I asked the support but until now did not get any response.

I need the following features
1. Rows and Columns
2. RowSpan, ColumnSpan
3. Fill the cells with child controls
4. Stretching and aligning capabilities inside the cells
5. DevExpress Skinnig and Theming

Maybe extending of some similar control would be an option ?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [XtraLayout control](http://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/layout/), although it works differently.

Comment: Yes but I can't make rows and columns with the  XtraLayout control.

Comment: Yes, you can.  Drag controls to the edges of the layout area.

Answer (score 0):

[XtraGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/grid/)
Wil do these task in WinForm.

Comment: unfortunately XtraGrid can contain the data only and not other controls itself.

Comment: I use this control all the time you can use please look at http://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/grid/grid_view.xml GridView and you can use  repository** controls like  repositoryItems and all the XtraEditors http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1009

Comment: But does it work like WPF Grid ? I think no. It is more like a docking control.

Comment: I have not used the WPF DXGrid version of DevExpress, but from reading the product pages, it seems to be the same grid as I use from the XtraGrid suite.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the same.